# ui bootstrap show popover for specyfic element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have got dynamic content created by dynamic library, so for instant that library give me event :

```
vm.onItemClick = function (event, item){
  event.evelment --> htmlelement


};
```

can i add tooltip for that element using ui bootstrap? 
I know that `AngularStrap` has `$popover` service,and i can not found similar service in uiBootstrap :/

Comment: it should be pretty easy, have you looked at https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover ?

Comment: Yes but this is directive i need service that can show popup.